# Excel - I need help to reduce redundancy of SUMIFS with date and keyword match

Tags: excel, date, date-range, sumifs

I am trying to gather the total cost of goods sold on various items as the products are sold, and grouping them by month to update a spreadsheet.

The SUMIFS formula I am using is extremely repetitive, due to the date constrictions, and I know there has to be an easier and cleaner way to produce the same results.

The formula I am currently using:

```
=SUM((SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),$C:$C,"Apple")*0.5)+(SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),$C:$C,"Banana")*0.75)+(SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),$C:$C,"Orange")*1.25))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the "Fruits" in a list somewhere?

Comment: Scott, It does not let me post pictures at this time, but I will try to write it out:

COLUMN A - DATE, 1/1/16, 1/3/16, 1/5/16, 1/20/16, 1/25/16, 2/5/16, 2/10/16

COLUMN B - Quantity, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1

COLUMN C - Item, Apple, Banana, Apple, Orange, Banana, Apple, Orange

I hope this helps.  Sorry, I'm still new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array formula. Enter the following formula and hit. CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),$C:$C,{"Apple","Banana","Orange"})*{0.5,0.75,1.25})
```

Comment: I updated the answer, I realized the first answer I posted wouldn't work like I thought. I have tested this one though.

Comment: Apathy, the formula worked great!  However, the cost values (0.5, 0.75, 1.25) are sourced from a cell on a different sheet.  When I change the values to the cell source, it does not accept it.  I apologize for not including it in the original coding, I figured it would've made it more confusing.

Comment: you can replace the cost values array at the end ( {0.50, 0.75, 1.25} ) with the range of cells that the cost are in, for example if they were on sheet 2 cells B1 to B3:
`=SUM(SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),$C:$C,{"Apple","Banana","Orange"})*Sheet2!B1:B3)`

Comment: Further clarification - you use curly braces { }  if you are listing an array of constants - if you are referencing cells you don't use the curly braces, you just enter the range.

Comment: I learned something new today!  Never knew the use of curly braces.

Not to throw a wrench in the mix, but the costs it draws from are on multiple rows.  It might help to know this is for cost of goods sold for inventory, and the inventory is separated by product category on different rows

Comment: i.e.-
ROW A - Apple, Banana, Orange
ROW B - 0.5, 0.75, 1.25
ROW F - Boxes, Tape
ROW G - 1.10, 0.8
etc.

Comment: Apathy, I have tried several combinations with and without the curly braces sourcing from another page, and I get results varying from 0.00 to #VALUE.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use a non-adjacent range in an array formula - never had to before. Meanwhile, would it be possible to create helper range where you bring the relevant costs together so you can use a regular range like b1:b3 (could hide it out of view somewhere)

Comment: I was re-reading your post and if you have the values together across a ROW in A2, B2, & C2, you can still use a range, instead of `Sheet2!B1:B3` it would be `Sheet2!A2:C2`

Comment: Apathy,  I set the items and cogs values in a hidden cell on the page.  I have it set up so if I add a new product in the future, it automatically places it in its proper place within the list.  So it would read - ROW A - Apples, Bananas, etc. ROW B - 0.5, 0.75, etc.  If I added 'Grapes' later, it would update to Apples, Grapes, Bananas, etc. with the associated cogs price.  I tried using the formula after ...$C:$C, Sheet2!A2:A10)*Sheet2!B2:B10) - and it zeros out the equation... Note - Cells A&B 3-10 remain blank currently.

Comment: would it be possible to see a copy of your workbook or a screenshot?

Comment: If you have only items listed in ROW 1 and only cost values listed in ROW 2, you can use an offset function to define your range so that it grows as you add items. Here is the new full equation:
`=SUM(SUMIFS($B:$B,$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),$C:$C,OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,1,COUNTA(Sheet2!1:1)))*OFFSET(Sheet2!A2,0,0,1,COUNTA(Sheet2!2:2)))`

Comment: I would love to take a screenshot, but I cannot upload images yet, I still need a few more rep points as I still very new.  I know this would make it tremendously easier too.  I tried the formula and it is zeroing out.  Would it be easier if I earned the remaining rep points and post a new question with pics?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot to a picture hosting website and post the link or upload a copy of the workbook to google drive and paste the link?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/snvwe

I have labeled the different pages with detailed descriptions for each which should help more than what I can provide on here at this time.  If you need additional information, I can update it as needed.

Comment: I created a new workbook based off the picture you sent and the formula is working for me. If you are entering the total COGS formula we are creating on a different sheet than the sales data, make sure you are adding the sheet reference into the formula. Here is the formula I have based on your pictures in cell B4 on the P&L page:
`=SUM(SUMIFS(Sales!$B:$B,Sales!$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),Sales!$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),Sales!$C:$C,OFFSET(Inventory!B1,0,0,1,COUNTA(Inventory!1:1)))*OFFSET(Inventory!B2,0,0,1,COUNTA(Inventory!2:2)))`

Comment: I tried plugging this formula into my spreadsheet and it was zeroed out again.  I tried on the template sheet I sent you and it gave me a value of 3.  But when I add up the cogs manually (based on quantities sold), the true cogs was 9.25.

Comment: The reason you would get 3 on the template sheet is that you didn't enter it as an array formula. After entering the formula you have to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (every time)... the whole formula should have { } around it when entered correctly. Try this on both sheets and if it still doesn't give you the correct result on your actual spreadsheet, I will need to know more about the method you use to add the new products and cogs to the top 2 hidden rows that you are referencing in the formula.

Comment: I tried the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER at the end of the formula on the template example and it added the curly brackets { } to the entire formula; however, it returns with #VALUE

Comment: Copy and paste the formula you have in the template sheet, so I can see it. Also, let me know how you get the cells in the top 2 rows to update.

Comment: This is the copy/paste formula --- {=SUM(SUMIFS(Sales!$B:$B,Sales!$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),Sales!$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),Sales!$C:$C,OFFSET(Inventory!B1,0,0,1,COUNTA(Inventory!1:1)))*OFFSET(Inventory!B2,0,0,1,COUNTA(Inventory!2:2)))}

Comment: For updating the Inventory page, I have a two step process.  There are 3 additional lines beneath the two I sent you in the template.  Line 1 consists of a code to number any cells  containing words using formula -- =IF(B5="","",MAX($A$4:A4)+1) --- The line below this is a simple =CELL equation to draw the words as they are entered in the different categories, leaving many blank cells between categories for expansion later.  The third line uses the same =CELL formula as the second, matching the cogs with the appropriate item... the second portion consists of an =ERROR formula to push...

Comment: ... all the blank cells to the end of the list.  This formula --- =IFERROR(INDEX($B$5:$CM$5,MATCH(COLUMN()-COLUMN($A$2),$B$4:$CM$4,0)),"") --- These are the formulas directly from my spreadsheets.  When I add a new item to the inventory, it places the item in the appropriate place within the list.

Comment: When I copied and pasted the formula you just pasted I got the same #Value error, I stepped through the formula to see where the error was coming in. The OFFSET functions weren't working properly. The formula was exactly right, but for some reason the OFFSET functions don't work when pasted. So I went back in and manually entered the end of the formula starting with the first OFFSET function after Sale!$C:$C and it worked. You could try that... If that doesn't do it for you I don't know if I can be of much more help without the actual workbook in front of me.

Comment: I created a template based off the one on my spreadsheet with all the formulas.  How should I send it to you?

Comment: Can you upload it to google drive or one drive and send a link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3psOsVXjkQENDVpcm94MUFXeDQ  ---- This should work for google drive.  Never used it before.

Comment: I can't open it until you grant access. You should have gotten an email.

Comment: I have opened it up for you.  Let me know if it is working.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by changing the way it sets the array size with the offset function. By using the COUNTA function it only ignores cells that are truly "empty". So it was still counting the cells with formulas returning null values. I changed it to take the MAX of the the index numbers you have setup in row 4 on the Inventory page. Here is the formula I got to work for the January COGS: `=SUM(SUMIFS(Sales!$G:$G,Sales!$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),Sales!$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),Sales!$H:$H,OFFSET(Inventory!B2,0,0,1,MAX(Inventory!4:4)))*OFFSET(Inventory!B3,0,0,1,MAX(Inventory!4:4)))`

Comment: Remember for some reason it won't always work when you copy and paste so you may need to enter the OFFSET functions manually. Also, you may need to re-enter the year in the date functions (don't ask me why, it's just something I've noticed works when I retype it but doesn't after pasting).

Comment: Apathy, It worked!!  Thank you so much!  You are truly a coding wizard.

Comment: Glad to hear. Not to add confusion, but it was bugging me that the Offset function was making it so finicky. So, I found an alternative way to make the ranges dynamics. Here is the new formula I came up with:
`=SUM(SUMIFS(Sales!$G:$G,Sales!$A:$A,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),Sales!$A:$A,"<="&DATE(2016,1,31),Sales!$H:$H,Inventory!$B$2:INDEX(Inventory!$B$2:$CZ$2,MAX(Inventory!4:4)))*(Inventory!$B$3:INDEX(Inventory!$B$3:$CZ$3,MAX(Inventory!4:4))))` ... this may be a better option as the offset will recalc every time any part of the book is changed, where this will only recalc when relevant data is changed.

Comment: Apathy, they both worked with copy paste for me.  I will copy this code for future reference though.  Thank you again for all of your help!  You were a true lifesaver!